# SSAS 2008 Dimension Wizard and the Date Template

Tags: time, ssas, multidimensional-array, bids

Does anyone know how to use the Date Template with the BIDS 2008, SSAS Project, Dimension Wizard? I keep getting an error - rightly so, I suppose - "Dimension not generated because it is bound to a time binding" (after having selected Generate a non-time table in the data source, in order to get to the Date template).

I am trying to do this as there is no Time dimension table in my data source.

Furthermore, I need time periods of HourOFDay, MinuteOfHour, and MinuteOfDay, which are not there if I go down the Generate a time table in the data source route.

In the meantime, I will go create the Time table from scratch, but it would be useful to know if I could achieve the same through some clever use of the Dimension Wizard.

Thank you,
Oana

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution here.

http://www.bronios.com/index.php/2010/04/01/error-the-time-dimension-was-not-generated-because-it-is-bound-to-a-time-binding/